# Load data before views in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to load some data via JSON from the web and save it globally to my app.

I have a separate swift file

```
 struct MyAppData {
  static var vendorCol = "15"
  static var vendorDel = "45"
  static var VendorID = "1"
}
```

Using alomofire i populate it.

```
    Alamofire.request("https://domainname/data.json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            guard let times = json["content"]["clients"].array else {
                print("No Data")
                return
            }

            for time in times {
                MyAppData.vendorCol = time["col"].string!
                MyAppData.vendorDel = time["del"].string!
                MyAppData.VendorID = time["id"].string!
            }

        }
    }
```

This works as expected if I place it on a view controller and use `MyAppData.VendorID`

My issue is I need a place load the data at a place where it's immediately available to all views and only want to load it once.

I tried in app delegate with no success, the function was called but the data was never updated all over the app. Some labels I set only had the default values from `MyAppData`.

Any help would be appreciated.